# Texture not being rendered by OBJMTLLoader

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I have a 3d model with texture that comes from Blender in OBJ/MTL/JPG format. But I cannot get this to render correctly with Three,js.

- The viewer code is [identical to the example on the three.js website](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_obj_mtl). I have only changed the paths to the OBJ and MTL files.
- I'm pretty sure all files are in the correct place. The OBJ and MTL files are loaded, and the path to the JPG in the MTL file is the correct path relative to the MTL file (there is a 404 if I change it).

Yet the result is a black model. [My example can be found here](http://www.danpearce.co.uk/static/3d/viewer_mtl.html). Can anyone put me out of my misery and tell me what I've done wrong?

For ease of reading:

- [The OBJ file](http://www.danpearce.co.uk/static/3d/obj/boeing/B737.obj)
- [The MTL file](http://www.danpearce.co.uk/static/3d/obj/boeing/B737.mtl)
- [The JPG file](http://www.danpearce.co.uk/static/3d/obj/boeing/B737_diff.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to understand what the parameters in your MTL file represent. Your diffuse reflectance and ambient reflectance are black -- not good. Change them to something reasonable, like so:

```
Kd 1.000 1.000 1.000     # white
Ka 1.000 1.000 1.000     # white
```

Or modify your loader callback function like so:

```
node.material.color.setRGB( 1, 1, 1 );
node.material.ambient.setRGB( 1, 1, 1 ); // no longer required (see Note)
```

---

Note: The `ambient` property of material has been removed from three.js, so you now only need to set the color.

three.js r.71

Comment: Thank you. That's helped hugely!

Comment: @DAN I suggest not to use **objmtlloader** because if your obj file size is greater than  4-5Mb browser will crash or take 1/2 min. to render object. You can use **jsonloader** works fine for me.