# Cannot load texture in obj+mtl file

Tags: javascript, three.js

I just follow this example: http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_obj_mtl.html

But my object loads without texture. I used a .obj and a .mtl file generated by Blender. What can I do to apply a texture to this object in Three.js?
Here is the object I want to load: http://tf3dm.com/3d-model/super-camputer-ibm-75503.html

How I load the object:

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
loader.load('obj/servidor.obj', 'obj/servidor.mtl', function(object) {

        object.position.y = -80;
        scene.add(object);

}, onProgress, onError);
```

Comment: We need some code.. question is too generic.. could be anything..

Comment: Now i added some code @Velthune

Comment: code seems ok, so problem could be on blender exporting. Generally, from what I just read, materials and textures should be "inside" mtl file.. so take a look here, maybe you simply have to set some scene/ambient paramenters http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24311026/texture-not-being-rendered-by-objmtlloader

Comment: My object does not load blank, it loads well but the texture is not applied. Here is my mtl file: http://pastie.org/10078588 @Velthune

Comment: What can i do to load the texture?

Comment: there is no texture defined in your mtl file. you are probably not exporting correctly from blender.

Comment: Nice! i applied the texture with Blender and then export obj again, now it works on Three.js!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the texture was not included in MTL file. I applied the texture with blender and generated obj and mtl again, now Three.js loads the object with texture (the javascript code from the question is ok)